# Prestashop default attribute not displayed correctly

Tags: attributes, combinations, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.7

I am using prestashop 1.7.7.4 and the product page does not display the default attribute correctly but the first in the combobox list.
I have checked on the database and the data is saved correctly.
This is the code for the product-variants.tpl page

```
    <select
      class="form-control form-control-select"
      id="group_{$id_attribute_group}"
      data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
      name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
      {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
        <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}"{if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected"{/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
      {/foreach}
    </select>
```

I can't figure out where the value of $group_attribute.selected is set.
Can anyone help me?

I have checked and the data in the database is saved correctly